# Bootstrap not wrapping columns with no size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So I am trying to make some bootstrap grid website to 'teach' myself a bit more about it. I've read the ins and outs that are posted **[here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)** and started to try and make the examples from that page.

Now in the very first example i ran into a problem, mainly what they show to be the 'behaviour' of columns which do not have a 'size' is that they all become equal in size and take up one row.

**Like so:**

[image]

**However, what I get instead is this:**

[image]

The colors and a bit of padding is the only thing I added to the baseline HTML/CSS page, which is what I copied from the example at the page i linked above, this is the extra CSS:

```
.row{
    /*background-color: lightblue;*/
    border: 3px solid rgba(86,61,124,.2);
}
.row>.col{
    padding-top: .75rem;
    padding-bottom: .75rem;
    background-color: rgba(86,61,124,.15);
    border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,.2);
}
```

The bootstrap CSS, js and jQuery has all been taken from the w3schools suggested CDN.

I do not know why my columns do not want to stack with one another as shown in the example, help pls.

Comment: looks like you are reading the documentation for bootstrap 4 alpha ([bootply of your code in 4](https://www.bootply.com/z5aUQKNCqK)), but using bootstrap 3 - [bootply of your code in 3](https://www.bootply.com/IgGas1aQTs) - here is the documentation for 3: http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: As @Pete mentioned. It could be possible that you might've been using bootstrap-3 cdn. Please try loading bootstrap 4 from the official site

Comment: @Pete okay that is highly likely the case then. How do I use bootstrap 4 though? I am using the CDN from w3schools. I do not know which one it gives me.

Comment: @Dellirium official website has everything - https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/

Comment: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/ (it is still in alpha at the moment - not officially released yet)

Comment: Will give it a go, was looking at: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download but all is related to version 3. Any specific reason not to use 4? Or has 4 became the new standard?

Comment: Okay seems to work when I use the CDN from there. Though, my IDE is reporting "errors" on the links due to attributes `integrity` and whatnot. Should I pay attention to this? Also is it considered bad to use Bootstrap 4 at this point, I am trying to learn for the future and since the behaviour is different it might be best to stick with version 3 for now. Oppinions?

Comment: As long as you are not wanting to support older browsers (ie9 sort of old) then I would use 4 (if you are not bothered about it still being in production) as flex is by far a better way to do layout and gives you a lot more options

Comment: The main difference in 3 vs 4 is flex vs tables yes? If that is the case then 4 it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's running without any changes - here is the code of [Bootstrap-v4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#equal-width)

```css
.row {
    /*background-color: lightblue;*/
    border: 3px solid rgba(86,61,124,.2);
}
.row > .col {
    padding-top: .75rem;
    padding-bottom: .75rem;
    background-color: rgba(86,61,124,.15);
    border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,.2);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      1 of 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then what is the issue with my page? There is literally nothing changed. Is it possible that the CDN doesn't provide the proper bootstrap? o.0

I am using the CDN links from w2school

Comment: @Ufgu Thanks for pointing out my error. Never thought about bootstrap 4

Comment: Accepted as answer, just want to point out that the main thing here is the "bootstrap 4"